# The type `Expander` was not found?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am getting an error that the type `Expander` was not found. I am aware that it was moved
in the Xamarin Community Toolkit, so I added this namespace on my `Content Page`;

```
xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
```

and used it like this.

```
<xct:Expander>
                        
</xct:Expander>
```

But I still get the error. Can someone help me with this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, you need to open the nuget package manager and install the package named `Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Markup` and the package named `Xamarin.CommunityToolkit`. In addition, the two packages always have dependency with the high version of `Xamarin.Form` packge.

So you can install the low version of the `CommunityToolkit` and `.CommunityToolkit.Markup` or update the Xamarin.Forms to the last version.

I suggest the latter and then add the namespace `xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"` in the Content Page, you can use the Expander.